# Override localhost on Windows XP

Tags: windows, networking

I have installed Windows XP and I want to override localhost from 127.0.0.1 to another address. I have edited `../windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`, however `ping localhost` still get response from 127.0.0.1. How can I change it indeed?

Comment: I am sure you *don't* want that. This sounds like trouble, problems and pain.

Comment: Explain why you would want to do this.

Comment: While editing `hosts` check out comment "localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself." which tells you can't use `hosts` for that. I don't believe there is an easy way to redirect `localhost` (and agree with @glglgl that it likely will lead to strange behavior).

Comment: Well, I installed Windows XP in a virtual machine. In host machine I run a web server. I want to access from vm in the same way as from the host machine.

Comment: So what stops you from using host's machine name instead of `localhost`?

Comment: In virtual machine I run a game client, and localhost is coded there (so in debug version I can choose a server to use). I don't want to put the name of the host's machine, because other team members don't need to know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is snippet from Windows hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

In other words, handling of localhost is hard-coded into Windows DNS stack, and your attempts to override that will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, for reference. It is useful to access a host on localhost from within a VM, so the configuration does not need modification.
The trick with hosts file worked in Windows 7, but failed on both XP and Windows 8. If you have specific ports you want to forward you can do that with netsh. Run a `cmd` prompt as Administrator, then:

For Windows XP first install ipv6:

```
netsh int ipv6 install
```

To add a forwarded port:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 80 192.168.1.123
```

All traffic to localhost on port 80 will now be forwarded to 192.168.1.123.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your problem, you could run a small server redirection program in your VM which upon an incoming connection contacts the host on the same port and feeds the data between these two sockets.

Imagine something like xinetd, listening on port 80 and executing `netcat hostmachine 80` or so.